# Using sed with a substitution variable that may have curly braces

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a script for looping over a set of files in a directory searching for a string (`stringA`) in one file (`srcFile`), copying the line that follows it (`stringToCopy`), and pasting it on the line after another search string (`stringB`) in another file (`outputFile`). The copy/paste script that I have so far is as follows

```
stringA="This is string A"
stringB="This is string B"
srcFile=srcFile.txt
outpuFile=outputFile.txt
replacement="/$stringA/{getline; print}"
stringToCopy="$(awk "$replacement" $srcFile)"
sed -i "/$stringB/!b;n;c${stringToCopy}" $outputFile
```

The script works great, except when `stringToCopy` ends up containing curly braces.  Example is

srcFile.txt:

```
This is string A
text to copy: {0}
```

outputFile.txt:

```
This is string B
line to be replaced
```

Once the script is done, I would expect `outputFile.txt` to be

```
This is string B
text to copy: {0}
```

But sed chokes with

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 106: unknown command: `m'
```

I've tried hardcoding the problematic string and trying different variations of escaping the curlies and quoting the string, but haven't found a winning combination and I'm at a loss for how to make it work.

*EDIT* 
I had a derp moment and forgot that my `stringA` also has curly braces, that happened to cause my awk command to math multiple lines. This caused my `stringToCopy` to have newlines in it which is my real issue, not the curly braces. So the real question is, how to make awk treat curly braces as literal characters so that 
`srcFile.txt`

```
This is string A: {0}
text to copy: {0}

This is string A:
Other junk
```

And `stringA="This is string A: {0}"`

Doesn't set `stringToCopy` to

```
text to copy: {0}
Other junk
```

Comment: The working way is to write the content of variable to temporary file and use `r` sed command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a kludge in that we're going to add some extra coding specifically for braces ...

Current situation:

```
$ awk '/This is string A: {0}/{getline; print}' srcFile.txt
text to copy: {0}                   # this is the line we want
Other junk                          # we do not want this line
```

We can eliminate the second line by escaping the braces in the search pattern, eg:

```
$ awk '/This is string A: \{0\}/{getline; print}' srcFile.txt
text to copy: {0}
```

So, how to escape the braces?  We can use some explicit parameter expansions to replace the braces with escaped braces in the `$stringA` variable, keeping in mind that we also need to escape the braces in the parameter expansion phase, too:

```
$ stringA="This is string A: {0}"
$ stringA="${stringA//\{/\\{}"      # replace '{' with '\{'
$ stringA="${stringA//\}/\\}}"      # replace '}' with '\}'
$ echo "${stringA}"
This is string A: \{0\}
```

We can then proceed with the rest of the code as is:

```
$ replacement="/$stringA/{getline; print}"
$ echo "${replacement}"
/This is string A: \{0\}/{getline; print}

$ stringToCopy="$(awk "$replacement" $srcFile)"
$ echo "${stringToCopy}"
text to copy: {0}
```

As for the final `sed` step I had to remove the `!` to get it to work correctly:

```
$ sed -i "/$stringB/b;n;c${stringToCopy}" $outputFile
$ cat "${outputFile}"
This is string B
text to copy: {0}
```

**NOTES**:

- if you preface your coding with `set -xv` you can see how variables are being interpreted at each step; use `set +xv` to turn off
- obviously you'll probably run into issues if you do in fact have more than 1 matching row in `$srcFile`
- if you find other characters that need to be escaped then you'll need to add additional parameter expansions for said characters